# "in list" vs. "manual searching" in list

Tags: python, indexing

My code in Python reads a next element in list and checks whether it already appeared in the list before. If yes, then it moves a left bound of the list behind the previous appearance (the rest of the code does not matter):

```
while k<len(lst):
    if lst[k] in lst[a:k]: #a is a left bound
       i = lst.index(lst[k],a) #could be done more effeciently with exception handling
       a = i+1
    k += 1
```

I tried to rewrite this without using high-level tricks (in/index):

```
    while k<len(lst):
      for i in range(a,k+1):
        if lst[i] == lst[k]:
            break
      if i != k: #different indices, same values
        a = i+1
      k += 1
```

This appears to be cca 3.5 times slower than the code #1. But I do not think the code #2 does something highly inefficient, if I understand the "in" command correctly.

```
go through all elements in list
compare to the searched element
if they are equal, stop and return True
if at end of the list, return False
```

(and the function *index* probably works in the same way, you only have to remember also the index).

My guess is that the Python interpreter interprets the "in" as a low-level version of the for-cycle in code #2. But in the code #2, it has to interpret my comparison every time I increase the value of i, which makes the code run slowly overall. Am I right about this?

By the way, the list is an ordered list of non-repeating numbers (does not have to be, so no suggestions of binary search), which results in a worst-case complexity for this algorithm, n^2/2.

Comment: You can use `dis.dis` to see the byte code generated for each. The explicit Python-level iteration is indeed the problem. `list.__contains__` is implemented, like the rest of the `list` type, in C (for CPython).